# while-loop will execute when there is a 0 in the while condition?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Let's see the example code:

```
 var limit = 3;
 while(limit--){
   console.log(limit);
   if(limit){
     console.log("limit is true");
   }else{
     console.log("limit is false")
   }
 }
```

and the output will be:

```
2
"limit is true"
1
"limit is true"
0
"limit is false"
```

There is a 0, which means false in the last time while condition. Why the last time loop will execute?

Comment: It will first check (`limit` is still 1) and then decrement it.

Comment: Look at what side the `--` is of the var limit.. it's on the right, meaning it will decrements after the comparison.  If you want before you need `--limit` instead.

Comment: The Reason is Post-decrement decreases the value after the operation has performed

Comment: Thank you ALL! I got it.

Answer (score 8):

`limit--` It is a post decrement. So when the `limit` is at `1` it resolves to `true` inside `while`  and then it is actually decrementing hence when you printing it is `0`.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(limit--)
```

equals

```
while(limit){
    limit = limit -1;
}
```

so the limit is from 3 to 1 in while expression,
while in braces, limit is from 2 to 0, so 'limit is false' will be executed.
if you expect 'limit is false' doesn't execute, you can replace `limit--` with `--limit`

Answer (score 3):

As you are using post increment it will first check condition and then will perform decrement on that variable so here while(limit--) will be treated as while(limit).

> ## DRY RUN:

```
var limit = 3;
```

> first time:

```
while(limit--){     //check limit while limit = 3 returns true and then decrement by 1 
   console.log(limit);  //so now print limit as 2
   if(limit){  //check limit while limit = 2
     console.log("limit is true");  //so now print this one
   }else{
     console.log("limit is false")
   }
 }
```

> second time:

```
while(limit--){     //check limit while limit = 2 returns true and then decrement by 1 
   console.log(limit);  //so now print limit as 1
   if(limit){     //check limit while limit = 1
     console.log("limit is true");  //so now print this one
   }else{
     console.log("limit is false")
   }
 }
```

> third time:

```
while(limit--){     //check limit while limit = 1 returns true and then decrement by 1 
   console.log(limit);  //so now print limit as 0
   if(limit){     //check limit while limit = 0
     console.log("limit is true");  
   }else{
     console.log("limit is false")  //so now print this one
   }
 }
```

> fourth time:

it will not go in while loop as now limit = 0

Answer (score 0):

In several languages, `0` value is considered as a `false` value.

Also `limit--` makes the decrement after being evaluated by the `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way to look at it. We're looking at a number and seeing if it's above 0 before if it is we're taking away 1 and then running through the loop again otherwise we're stopping there.

```js
let three = 3, two = 2, one = 1, zero = 0;

console.log('3--: ' + (three-- > 0));
console.log('2--: ' + (two-- > 0));
console.log('1--: ' + (one-- > 0));
console.log('0--: ' + (zero-- > 0));
```